# REST API Working for GET but not for POST?

Tags: posts, get-posts, api, rest-api

I am trying to create a post through the REST API.

I am able to access the API by getting the existing posts, as per the screenshot below:

[image: Get Posts]

However, when I try to do a similar request to create a new post, the API responds that I am not allowed to create posts:

[image: Create Post]

I have tried submitting the request with my admin credentials, as well as with an editor user I created just for this. I am using basic authentication just to check if the process is working, and after that I will switch to JWT or OAuth.

What am I missing here?

UPDATE: Added a screenshot with Postman authorization tab, as that was not visible from the previous screenshot.

[image]

I have also tried 2 different approaches of changing .htaccess but none of them has worked. I tried adding both

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.)
RewriteRule ^(.) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

When I do a GET request to wp-json endpoint, I don't see any authentication method. Is basic authentication supposed to appear there?

[image]

Comment: You say you're using basic authentication, but I don't see any authentication being used in your screenshots.

Comment: @JacobPeattie If you take a look at the second screenshot, there is a blue dot besides Authorization signalling that authorization was being used. I could not send a screenshot showing several tabs of postman, so I showed the payload of the request. I now added a third screenshot with the authorization tab.

Comment: https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth/issues/35 - this may assist?

Comment: @Aravona I have also tried that, no luck. I will add this to the question just to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ignoring the csrf. If not you can do it by creating a new Configuration file.
Here is the configuration code to tell spring to ignore the csrf( Cross Site Request Forging) for us.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity.csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/api/**");
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

Try this and let me know if it doesn't work.